eslint (with types) + svelte v5 fail?
seems like something is perhaps broken using svelte v5 with eslint rules (with type checking enabled):
(start with minimal app e.g. npx sv create foo (typescript + eslint))
minimally change eslint.config.js to add typed rules:
import js from '@eslint/js';
import svelte from 'eslint-plugin-svelte';
import globals from 'globals';
import ts from 'typescript-eslint';

export default ts.config(
  {
    ignores: ['*.config.js'],
  },

  js.configs.recommended,
  ...ts.configs.recommendedTypeChecked, // *** changed
  ...svelte.configs['flat/recommended'],
  {
    languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        ...globals.browser,
        ...globals.node,
      },

      // *** ADDED
      parserOptions: {
        projectService: true,
        tsconfigRootDir: import.meta.dirname,
        extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.svelte'],

    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        parser: ts.parser,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    ignores: ['build/', '.svelte-kit/', 'dist/'],
  }
);

Although tsc has no problems (it knows the type of id is string, eslint doesn't seem to pick up sveltekit-generated types:
/routes/[id]/+server.ts:

BTW, this does work:
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types';

export const GET: RequestHandler = ({ params: { id } }) => {
  return json({ id });
};

But shouldn't be necessary and is a regression in DX IMO. This all worked well in svelte 4 + eslint 8, but I don't know which upgrade causes this new problem.
Advice/help appreciated!
